# Closed sets in different topologies

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

I've gone though this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492244/a-normed-vector-space-is-normed-closed-iff-it-is-weakly-closed?noredirect=1&lq=1) and I don't really understand the statement: "A-convergence implies B-convergence, then B-closed implies A-closed"

If $\tau_1\subset \tau_2$, where $\tau_1$ is a topology weaker than $\tau_2$ in some space $X$, then a closed set in $(X, \tau_1)$ is closed in $(X,\tau_2)$

Why is this true? I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Comment: A subset E of X that belongs to tau_1 (i.e. that is called "open" in tau_1) must also belong to tau_2 (i.e. be called "open" in tau_2). What is the definition of a closed set in an abstract topological space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y\subset X$ be closed in $(X, \tau_1 )$.  Then $Y^\complement \in \tau_1$, which implies $Y^\complement \in \tau_2$, so $Y=(Y^\complement)^\complement$ is closed in $(X, \tau_2)$

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense.

If we are given that every sequence/net that converges in $\tau_2$ also converges in $\tau_1$, can we argue that a set $K$ that is closed in $\tau_1$ is also closed in $\tau_2$ using the definition that a closed set contains all of its accumulation points?

Comment: @Matthew yes, but the above method is arguably more direct. To see what I mean, prove the property about nets or sequences, from the hypothesis that tau_1 is contained in tau_2.

Answer (score 1):

If $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$ then $\tau_2$-convergent implies $\tau_1$-convergent, because convergence (sequences/nets/filters) is always defined as "bla converges to $x$" iff "for all open sets containing $x$, something about bla" so if we can do that for all sets in $\tau_2$, we certainly can for $\tau_1$ too.

And $\tau_2$-convergent implies $\tau_1$-convergent means "$\tau_1$-closed implies $\tau_2$-closed": suppose $F$ is $\tau_1$ closed, then suppose a "bla" in $F$ $\tau_2$-converges to $x$, then "bla" $\tau_1$-converges to $x$ so $x \in F$ as $F$ is $\tau_1$-closed, so $F$ is $\tau_2$-closed (which is usually characterised as "for every "bla" on the $F$ that converges to some $x \in X$, $x \in F$".

But of course the direct route is much easier, go via complements. But the convergence "reversal" is good to realise too.