# (Weak) basis for the space of bounded sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

The canonical basis is not a Schauder basis of the space of bounded sequences, but in some way, it uniquely determines every element in the space. Is it a basis in a weaker sense? How is it called?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's a Schauder basis of $c_0$, the sequences with limit $0$.  I don't see in what sense it "uniquely determines" anything not in $c_0$.  Maybe you're thinking of a basis of $\ell^1$, whose dual is $\ell^\infty$?

Comment: That makes sense, any sequence in $\ell^\infty$ can be understood as a operator of $\ell^1$ sequences. Then we can take a Schauder basis of $\ell^1$ and describe the behavior of the $\ell^\infty$ operator through the images of the basis elements.

Thanks! I will post it as solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

A subspace of a normed vector space is closed if and only if it is weakly closed [Closed $\iff$ weakly closed subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449301/closed-iff-weakly-closed-subspace). Hence, a set is a Schauder basis if and only if it is a "basis in the weaker sense".

Answer (score 0):

Any sequence in $\ell^\infty$ can be understood as a operator of $\ell^1$ sequences. Then we can take a Schauder basis of $\ell^1$ and describe the behavior of the $\ell^\infty$ operator through the images of the basis elements.